# How do I mask multi-output in Tensorflow 2 LSTM training?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am training an LSTM model in Tensorflow 2 to predict two outputs, streamflow and water temperature.

- For some of the time steps there is a streamflow label ***and*** a temperature label,
- For some there is only a streamflow label ***or*** a temperature label,
- and for some there are ***neither***.

So the loss function needs to ignore the temperature and streamflow loss when they don't have a label. I've done quite a bit of reading in the TF docs, but I'm struggling to figure out how to best do this.

So far I've tried

- specifying `sample_weight_mode='temporal'` when compiling the model and then included a `sample_weight` numpy array when calling `fit`

When I do this, I get an error asking me to pass a 2D array. But that confuses me because there are 3 dimensions: `n_samples`, `sequence_length`, and `n_outputs`.

Here's some code of what I am basically trying to do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# set up the model
simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae',
                          sample_weight_mode='temporal')

n_sample = 2
seq_len = 10
n_feat = 5
n_out = 2

# random in/out
x = np.random.randn(n_sample, seq_len, n_feat)
y_true = np.random.randn(n_sample, seq_len, n_out)

# set the initial mask as all ones (everything counts equally)
mask = np.ones([n_sample, seq_len, n_out])
# set the mask so that in the 0th sample, in the 3-8th time step
# the 1th variable is not counted in the loss function
mask[0, 3:8, 1] = 0

simple_lstm_model.fit(x, y_true, sample_weight=mask)
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (2, 10, 2). In order to use timestep-wise sample weighting, you should
pass a 2D sample_weight array.
```

Any ideas? I must not understand what `sample_weights` do because to me it only makes sense if the `sample_weight` array has the same dimensions as the output. I could write a custom loss function and handle the masking manually, but it seems like there should be a more general or built in solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. `sample_weights`

Yes, you understand it incorrectly. In this case you have `2` samples, `10` timesteps with `5` features each. You could pass `2D` tensor like this so each timestep for each sample will contribute differently to total loss, all features are equally weighted (as is usually the case).

**That's not what you are after at all**. You would like to mask certain loss values after their calculation so those do not contribute.

### 2. Custom loss

One possible solution is to implement your own loss function which multiplies loss tensor by mask before taking `mean` or `sum`.

Basically, you pass `mask` and `tensor` concatenated together somehow and split it within function for use. This is sufficient:

```
def my_loss_function(y_true_mask, y_pred):
    # Recover y and mask
    y_true, mask = tf.split(y_true_mask, 2)
    # You could user reduce_sum or other combinations
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.abs(y_true - y_pred) * mask)
```

Now your code (no weighting as it's not needed):

```
simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=True), tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)]
)

simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=my_loss_function)

n_sample = 2
seq_len = 10
n_feat = 5
n_out = 2

x = np.random.randn(n_sample, seq_len, n_feat)
y_true = np.random.randn(n_sample, seq_len, n_out)

mask = np.ones([n_sample, seq_len, n_out])
mask[0, 3:8, 1] = 0

# Stack y and mask together
y_true_mask = np.stack([y_true, mask])

simple_lstm_model.fit(x, y_true_mask)
```

And so it works. You could also stack the values in some other way, but I hope you get the feel of how one could do it.

### 3. Masking outputs

Please notice above introduces a few problems. If you have a lot of zeroes and take `mean` you might get a really small loss value and inhibit learning. On the other hand, if you go with `sum` it might explode.